# C# Loading non-thread-safe DLL multiple times using AppDomain or Process

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, process, appdomain

I have a non-thread-safe DLL that contains static methods and data. I need to call its methods from different objects and possibly threads keeping everything separated. Google says I have to create different AppDomains (in this case one for each object calling the DLL) or create a new Process. Is that true? If yes which one is the best solution and How do I practically do it? If not is there any other solution?

Also, I have a Form instantiating the class that uses the DLL and I need to be able to access the methods inside the class from the Form. Will I be able to do that?

To make it clearer I post some code.
The DLL import goes like this:

```
namespace ASCOM.QHYCCD
{
    public class libqhyccd
    {
        [DllImport("import/qhyccd.dll", EntryPoint = "InitQHYCCDResource",
            CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public unsafe static extern UInt32 InitQHYCCDResource();

        [DllImport("import/qhyccd.dll", EntryPoint = "GetQHYCCDSingleFrame",
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public unsafe static extern UInt32 GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(IntPtr handle, ref UInt32 w, ref UInt32 h, ref UInt32 bpp, ref UInt32 channels, byte* rawArray);
        public unsafe static UInt32 C_GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(IntPtr handle, ref UInt32 w, ref UInt32 h, ref UInt32 bpp, ref UInt32 channels, byte[] rawArray)
        {
            UInt32 ret;
            fixed(byte* prawArray = rawArray)
                ret = GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(handle, ref w, ref h, ref bpp, ref channels, prawArray);
            return ret;
        }

        // a lot more stuff like this

    }
}
```

And this is the class:

```
class QHYCamera
{
    public static IntPtr handler;
    private bool isConnected = false;
    uint width, height, bpp, channels;
    double chipw, chiph, pixelw, pixelh;
    byte[] rawArray;
    uint arrayLength;

    public QHYCamera(){}

    public void Connect(int index, string strid)
    {
        if (!isConnected)
        {
            //ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.InitQHYCCDResource();
            StringBuilder id = new StringBuilder(strid);
            //ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.GetQHYCCDId(index, id);
            handler = ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.OpenQHYCCD(id);
            Console.WriteLine(handler.ToString());
            ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.SetQHYCCDStreamMode(handler, 0);
            ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.InitQHYCCD(handler);
            ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.GetQHYCCDChipInfo(handler, ref chipw, ref chiph, ref width, ref height, ref pixelw, ref pixelh, ref bpp);
            ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.SetQHYCCDBinMode(handler, 1, 1);
            ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.SetQHYCCDResolution(handler, 0, 0, width, height);
            arrayLength = ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.GetQHYCCDMemLength(handler);
            rawArray = new byte[arrayLength];
            isConnected = true;
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (isConnected)
        {
            ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.CloseQHYCCD(handler);
            ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.ReleaseQHYCCDResource();
            isConnected = false;
        }
    }

    public bool IsConnected()
    {
        return isConnected;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> GetAvailableCameras()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> index_id = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.ScanQHYCCD(); i++)
        {
            StringBuilder id = new StringBuilder(200);
            ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.GetQHYCCDId(i, id);
            index_id.Add(id.ToString(), i);
        }
        return index_id;
    }

    public void SetExposure(double exposure)
    {
        if (ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.SetQHYCCDParam(handler, StructModel.CONTROL_ID.CONTROL_EXPOSURE, exposure) == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot set exposure", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    public void SetGain(double gain)
    {
        if (ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.SetQHYCCDParam(handler, StructModel.CONTROL_ID.CONTROL_GAIN, gain) == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot set exposure", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    public Task<Bitmap> GetBitmapAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return GetBitmap();
        });
    }

    public Bitmap GetBitmap()
    {
        ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.SetQHYCCDBitsMode(handler, bpp);
        ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.InitQHYCCD(handler);
        ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.ExpQHYCCDSingleFrame(handler);

        uint ret = 1;
        while(ret != 0)
        {
            ret = ASCOM.QHYCCD.libqhyccd.C_GetQHYCCDSingleFrame(handler, ref width, ref height, ref bpp, ref channels, rawArray);
        }

        if (ret == 0)
        {
            Color[] palette = new Color[256];
            for (Int32 b = 0; b < 256; b++)
                palette[b] = Color.FromArgb(b, b, b);
            return BuildImage(rawArray, (int)width, (int)height, (int)width, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, palette, null);
        }
        return default(Bitmap);
    }

    public static Bitmap BuildImage(Byte[] sourceData, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 stride, PixelFormat pixelFormat, Color[] palette, Color? defaultColor)
    {
        Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
        BitmapData targetData = newImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, newImage.PixelFormat);
        Int32 newDataWidth = ((Image.GetPixelFormatSize(pixelFormat) * width) + 7) / 8;
        Boolean isFlipped = stride < 0;
        stride = Math.Abs(stride);
        Int32 targetStride = targetData.Stride;
        Int64 scan0 = targetData.Scan0.ToInt64();
        for (Int32 y = 0; y < height; y++)
            Marshal.Copy(sourceData, y * stride, new IntPtr(scan0 + y * targetStride), newDataWidth);
        newImage.UnlockBits(targetData);
        if (isFlipped)
            newImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
        if ((pixelFormat & PixelFormat.Indexed) != 0 && palette != null)
        {
            ColorPalette pal = newImage.Palette;
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < pal.Entries.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i < palette.Length)
                    pal.Entries[i] = palette[i];
                else if (defaultColor.HasValue)
                    pal.Entries[i] = defaultColor.Value;
                else
                    break;
            }
            newImage.Palette = pal;
        }
        return newImage;
    }

}
```

From the main form I just need to instantiate the class, spawn a new thread that calls some methods:

```
private void BackgroundPreviewHandler(QHYCamera camera)
{
     while (camera.IsConnected())
     {
         Bitmap bitmap = camera.GetBitmap();
         PictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
     }
}

private QHYCamera visibleCam = new QHYCamera();
private QHYCamera halphaCam = new QHYCamera();

await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => BackgroundPreviewHandler(visibleCam));
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => BackgroundPreviewHandler(halphaCam));
```

Comment: AppDomains only apply to managed code.  You have to create multiple processes.  Use the standard .NET process interop mechanisms to talk to them.  Probably WCF here, although it is not obvious why a camera needs a lot of pinvoke.  Perhaps you need a process produce only the bitmap with all the pinvoke inside that process, a named pipe then.

Comment: I need to put the camera object into a separate process because otherwise when I call initQHYCCDresource() it crashes saying I&#39;m accessing protected memory. So each process will instantiate the dll and its memory will be independent?